# Analysing the meter used in poetry

Tags: text-processing, plain-text

I'm looking for a tool which can take a poem, presumbably in the form of a text file, and annotate it with useful information related to the meter used in the poem, such as

- Number of lines in each verse.
- Number of syllables in each line.
- The stresses on the syllables.  I don't seem to be able to figure out the stressed and unstressed syllables in iambic pentameter on my own, so this would be particularly helpful!
- Identify groups of lines that end in words which rhyme.

(the returned format might also text, html, or a data format such as JSON or YAML)

I want to run it on existing poems, such as sonnets and haikus, and maybe make a few laughable attempts at writing my own poems.

I realise such a tool would have quite a specialised dictionary behind it.  Many years ago I was playing with the Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) in Python, so I know such dictionaries exist.  I've also found syllable counters online, but not a nice one, and I'd probably prefer an open source tool I could download.